# MySQL - Use Count Without Where in Left Join

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

My table looks as follows:

**Products**

```
 id       title      price 
--------------------------------------
  5       777        15         
  6       777        16
  7       777        14
```

**Product Details**

```
 id       pid      quantity       color
--------------------------------------
  1       5       5               red
  2       5       5               yellow
  3       5       5               green
  4       6       6               yellow
  5       6       5               red
  6       7       5               red
  7       7       4               pink
```

I want to get following output:

**Desired Results**

```
  id      title      price  numberofdetails quantity
------------------------------------------------------
  5       777        15         3           15
  6       777        16         2           11
  7       777        14         2           9
```

In order to get this i am running following mysql query:

**Query**

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, COUNT(pd.id), SUM(pd.quantity) 
FROM products as p 
LEFT JOIN productdetails as pd 
ON p.id = pd.pid
```

The wrote this query assuming that since I have defined the relationship between products.id and productdetails.pid it would COUNT(pd.id) = 3. Instead of counting only matching rows it shows '7', the total number of rows. How can I fix my query to get the desired results as show above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.  I think you just need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, COUNT(pd.id), SUM(pd.quantity)
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     productdetails pd
     ON p.id = pd.pid
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.price;
```

In most databases, your query would return an error.  However, MySQL extends the definition of SQL to allow columns in the `SELECT` (such as `p.id`) that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  Because of the aggregation functions, you have an aggregation query.  Without a `GROUP BY`, it always returns one rows, which summarizes all the data.

Comment: who knew GROUP BY would be so valuable :P Thanks a lot for the explanation. I hope I don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, COUNT(pd.id), SUM(pd.quantity)
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     productdetails pd
     ON p.id = pd.pid
GROUP BY p.id

group by p.id is enough

Comment: try with only group by p id